# How to attach files to a pytest test in allure framework

Tags: allure

How can I attach files to a test. For example I would like to add kml files (an XML notation for expressing geographic annotation and visualization within two-dimensional maps and three-dimensional Earth browsers). 
any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Using `allure.attach` you can add html content to any test you have.

```py
def test_multiple_attachments():
    allure.attach.file('./data/totally_open_source_kitten.png', attachment_type=allure.attachment_type.PNG)
    allure.attach('<head></head><body> a page </body>', 'Attach with HTML type', allure.attachment_type.HTML)
```

[Read the docs](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_steps_5)

```html
<script>
      var map;
      var src = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/kml/westcampus.kml';
```

[Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kml) you have a tutorial how you can display *.kml content in a html file.